# required_if not case in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this validation:

```
 'target' => ['required', Rule::in(['ads', 'users',...])],
 'expires_at' => 'required_if:target,!=,ads',
```

I need to make `expires_at` is not required if the `target` is `ads` if the user chooses other options make `expires_at` required again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `required_unless`.

```
 'expires_at' => 'required_unless:target,ads',
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-unless) is the documentation for that rule.